# How to render one flask template inside other

Tags: python, flask

A flask template receives list of business contact details list - `catalogue.html`

I am trying to render a list of business cards in this template.
But for ease of coding, i want to send individual business info to - `card.html` ,
so that all grid-adjustments go in only one place and looks consistent all over the place.

is there a way to achieve this -

```
 {% for entry in datalist %}
   {{ card(data = entry) }}
 {% end for %}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is import, include and macro. Documented at https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html#list-of-control-structures

Comment: Thanks @MennoHölscher I was able to achieve what i wanted with this help. {% include ... %} is aware of parent context, it's charm.